# automatically create google contact from my google form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form that my clients fill out. How do I have the form create a google contact automatically each time someone new fills out the survey? I dont want to have to copy paste each time just to create a new contact in my gmail

I'm trying to use this script but getting an error when I try to run it with some test data

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
   var timestamp = e.values[0];
   var firstName= e.values[1];
   var lastName= e.values[2];
   var email= e.values[3];
   var phone= e.values[4]; 
   ContactsApp.createContact( timestamp  ,  firstName , lastName ,  email , phone );
 }
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2

Comment: When you run this function manually via the script editor you don't get an `e` parameter object like you get when its being triggered automatically. That's why its `undefined`. To run it manually you have initialize the `e` parameter with some testing values.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error message when attempting to run the function manually, as there is no event being passed to the function.

Disregard the remainder of the post (see Henrique's comment).

> According to the documentation:
>
> An event is passed to every event handler as the argument (e) . You
> can add attributes to the (e) argument that further define how the
> trigger works or that capture information about how the script was
> triggered.
>
> If you use the attributes, you must still set the trigger from the
> Resources menu, as described in the sections above.
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#TriggerAttributes
>
> I can't explain why this is the case, but it seems you need to use the
> simple event handler (ie naming the function onFormSubmit), as well as
> applying an installable event handler to that same function.  Then,
> for me at least, it works as expected.
>
> HTH, Adam

Comment: i have set my trigger to run on form submit;  should i see a new contact in my google account immediately or does it take a while; has not worked for me yet

Comment: function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var firstName= e.values[1];
 var lastName= e.values[2];
 var email= e.values[3];
 var phone= e.values[4]; 

  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact( firstName , lastName ,  email , phone );
  }

Comment: @AdamL there's no simple event handler for 'on form sumit', like there is for `onOpen` and `onEdit`. So, naming onFormSubmit has no effect at all, it could be any name. What is important is setting the installable trigger.

Comment: Oops, thanks for clarifying Henrique, I thought there was a simple event handler for that. @user1420867, not sure why it isn't working, will test when I get a chance, but docs say there are only 3 arguments in method: createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress)

Comment: i have used henrique script for 2 years to send form results and it has been a life saver;  now i am simply trying to automatically create a google contact from my survey; i have set up a test form with only 4 columns to try it out; my function is: function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var firstName= e.values[1];
 var lastName= e.values[2];
 var email= e.values[3];
 var phone= e.values[4]; 

 ContactsApp.createContact( firstName , lastName ,  email , phone );
  }  and i have trigger set to send on form submit;  no results so far

Answer (score 0):

There's no "phone" argument in `createContact` function. Before attempting to create it from a more difficult to debug trigger, have you tried writing a simple function to create a simple contact just to check that you got it right?

Also, I remember an [old error](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=291) with on form submit parameters, that may be back. Anyway, it doesn't hurt to add a `toString` in all your parameters. e.g.

```
var email = e.values[3].toString(); //just to be sure
```

Comment: function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var timestamp = e.values[0];
 var firstName= e.values[1];
 var lastName= e.values[2];
 var email = e.values[3].toString(); //just to be sure
  ContactsApp.createContact( firstName, lastName, email );
  }  ok tried it like this with very simple 3 column sheet but no contact created yet;  my trigger is just set to from spreadsheet/on form submit

Comment: I suggested you to try a simpler, direct code to add a contact, adding "complexity" later (e.g. running from a trigger). Have you tried it?

Comment: not sure how to do that, is there no trigger in what you suggest-so delete the trigger?  what would that simple code look like? is it in the same script area?

Comment: It would look like this: `function simplerTest() { ContactsApp.createContact("my","test","test@example.com"); }`. Then you start replacing it by parameters, etc.

Comment: this worked- function onFormSubmit(e) { var timestamp = e.values[0]; var firstName= e.values[1]; var lastName= e.values[2]; var email = e.values[3].toString(); //just to be sure ContactsApp.createContact( firstName, lastName, email ); } .  the contact shows up in my "other contacts"  label.  is there a way to direct it to the "mycontacts"  and if i have a column for cell phone can it add to the contact?

Comment: can i add cell phone and address fields to automatically populate?

Comment: Yes, but after you create the contact. use it's `addPhone` and `addAdress`. Take a look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contact

Comment: just learning....so do i add this to the other  script?  or it added as a script of its own?    method addPhone(label, number)

Comment: same script, right after you've created the contact. e.g. `var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(...` then `contact.addPhone(...`